# Why does "Library.ahk_ts" keeps appearing in $HOME directory?

Tags: finder, file, big-sur

Running macOS version 11.0 (20A5374i) {aka "Big Sur Beta 8"} on a 16" MacBook Pro.

I have noticed that a file named `Library.ahk_ts` keeps appearing in my home directory.

I am trying to figure out what app or process is creating it.

It appears to be a simple plist with a date/time stamp and nothing else:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <date>2020-09-23T18:58:43Z</date>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've deleted it a few times, only to re-appear in the next few days.

I don't think it's malicious or harmful. I'm just wondering where it came from (which app/process/etc) and why.

Google was no help.

Judging from the timestamp when the file was created (2:58 p.m. local time) I was on a Zoom call, but I had been on a Zoom call for about an hour, so I don't think it was anything Zoom related.

#stumped

Comment: TS probably stands for Time Stamp. AHK … Apple HomeKit maybe? HealthKit? Do you have smart home devices and / or a smart watch?

Comment: No Smart Watch, but do have home devices. Never seen this before, though…

Comment: Nobody has seen this before. This very question is literally the only mention of it ever in the entire history of mankind. Well, the subset that is recorded in Google anyway.